# Select HTML link based on anchor text in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I need to select the element labeled "Save" in the following HTML:

```
<td id="glActionAreaItem_0" tabindex="401" widgetid="glActionAreaItem_0">
   <a class="actionItem" dojoattachevent="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="401" href="javascript:void(0);"> Reset </a>
</td>    

<td id="ActionAreaItem_1" tabindex="402" widgetid="glActionAreaItem_1">
   <a class="actionItem" dojoattachevent="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="402" href="javascript:void(0);"> Save </a>
</td>
```

I need to grab the Save object, but there are very few unique fields between the Reset and Save objects, and I don't want to rely on the tabindex cause we are not guaranteed that will stay 402 forever.

Is it possible to use the 'Save' label as the XPath?  How would I go about doing that? Or perhaps I can use the `id="glActionAreaItem_1"` and somehow get that objects children, would that give me the Save object? Sorry, thinking out loud.

```
Dim btn_Save

'page is the HTML page
Set btn_Save = page.FindChildByXPath("//a[@tabindex='402']:, True)
```

I need another way to get the `btn_Save` object, not using the `tabindex` property because it is not going to be 402 always.

Comment: Don't get it. You wanna match the second `a` ?

Comment: PLease show what your expected output is.  Question is not clear.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Updated the question to include what I'm doing. I'm looking for a more reliable alternative. Ty

Comment: Why not find by **id** and/or **widgetid** attribute?

Comment: Other than comparing the result of `text()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get the Save object.

```
Set lnk_Save = page.FindChildByXPath("//td[@id='glActionAreaItem_1']//a[@class='actionItem']", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select an element based on its string value in XPath.

This XPath will select the `a` element whose string value is "Save":

```
//a[normalize-space(.) = 'Save']
```

That way it won't matter whether `@tabindex` or any other attribute changes.

(`normalize-space()` will trim away leading and trailing whitespace and consolidate internal space (not applicable here).)